# Как организовать цикл while для мониторинга файловой системы и не нагружать процессор на 100%?

Tags: python, циклы, файловая-система

Мне нужен постоянный контроль над файловой системой. Как это организовать без циклов, ума не приложу.

Пустой цикл while нагружает процессор на 80-100% на моей машине.

```
while True: pass
```

Это как-то решается?

Comment: Да. Это решается избавлением от пустого цикла.

Comment: @Xyanight, а Вы чего ожидали?

Comment: Как тогда быть с программой, которая постоянно должна рабатать в цикле?

Comment: @Xyanight,

1. В этой программе как раз не будет пустого цикла.
2. В конце каждой итерации можно устраивать sleep на безопасное время. Если вам нужен демон, то можно устроить реагирование на те или иные события, которые будут выводить программу из сна (как это сделать в однопоточном приложении - пока не знаю, но в многопоточном потоки стопорятся через простую очередь сообщений)

Comment: Мне нужен постоянный контроль над файловой системой. Как это организовать без циклов, ума не приложу.

Comment: Эта штука под названием ["busy-waiting" или "spinning"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) генерирует петли из задачи "ничего не делать" и такие петли не останавливаются и способны загрузить процессор и систему, которые не знают, что с этим делать. Банально не используйте пустые циклы: пробуйте отловить события системы, напишите там какой-нибудь код или усыпляйте поток через sleep.

Comment: @Xyanight, лучше напишите, что конкретно хотите делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странное решение... но, как вариант, поставить тайм-аут на секунду или сколько там нужно.

Comment: Решение не странное, и его специфика такова, что без единого цикла не обойтись. Впрочем, согласен, долгий сон в пару секунд, решает.

Answer (score 11):

> Мне нужен постоянный контроль над файловой системой. Как это организовать без циклов, ума не приложу.

Не нужно терроризировать ОС и диск на наличие изменений. Нужно просто попросить их сообщать о них. Это куда практичнее и надежнее. Для linux систем есть такая штука, как inotify. Просто указываете, что Вы хотите мониторить (создание файлов, удаление, изменение) и ждете. Для питона даже есть готовая обвязка - https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify. (пример посмотрите [здесь](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/04/monitoring-filesystem-python-and-pyinotify/).)

Если нужна поддержка винды, тогда посмотрите на [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/). На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140649/) есть детальное описание.

Если все же вышеприведенное не устраивает (например, ущербностью апи:) ), то можно конечно сделать и обычным циклом. Только не забудьте добавить в конец sleep на одну секунду. Для большинства задач +-1 секунда разницы никакой, а нагрузка на процессор упадет в разы. Возможно, даже 3-5 секунд sleep'a будет достаточно.

Comment: `watchdog` поддерживает несколько платформ, в частности этот пакет может использовать inotify на Linux.