# как совместить два скрипта, а то когда оба работают проц едят жестко

Tags: python, вконтакте

Подскажите такой момент, есть два бота постящие в вк в разные группы и берущие текст из разных файлов (пример одного ниже, второй отличается adres='C:\si2.txt' и api.wall.post(owner_id='-20', message=data)), как их в один запихать и как по возможности снизить нагрузку на процессор, а то мой G4500 (3.5GHz) на 100% загружен только этими двумя скриптами? (сильно не пинайте опыта очень мало)

```
import vk

token = "9455e5"
session = vk.Session(access_token=token)
api = vk.api.API(session, v='5.80', land='ru')
adres='C:\si1.txt'
position = 0
with open(adres) as fh:
    while True:
        fh.seek(position)
        data = fh.read()
        position = fh.tell()
        if data:
            api.wall.post(owner_id='-17', message=data)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как организовать цикл while для мониторинга файловой системы и не нагружать процессор на 100%?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/394841/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-while-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86)

Comment: @Andrio-Skur Ну, вопросы все же разные, хоть и близкие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

методом тыка нашел решение

```
 with open(adres1) as fh1, open(adres2) as fh2:
    while True:
        fh1.seek(position1)
        fh2.seek(position2)
        data1 = fh1.read()
        data2 = fh2.read()
        position1 = fh1.tell()
        position2 = fh2.tell()
        if data1:
            api.wall.post(owner_id='-17', message=data1)
        if data2:
            api.wall.post(owner_id='-16', message=data2)
```